# jquery form submit action doesn't work on document.ready

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
          url: "pages/"+page+".php",
          cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $('#main').html(html).css({"max-height":mH-30,"height":mH-30}).jScrollPane();

        $('form').not('#loginf').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var inputs = $(this).serialize();   
            $.ajax({
              url: "pages/"+page+".php?"+inputs+'&action='+param,
              cache: false
            }).done(function( html ) {
                update(html);
                rs();
            }).fail(function (){
                window.location = "/CMS/";
        });
    });
});
```

So the submit function on the forms doesn't work..

What's intresting is that I also have another ajax on the page when some li element get clicked and on the done function there I also have the form submit function and it works there.

Is there something wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, i solved it by looking into this question answers:

[problems with ajax request in page with form. jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016246/problems-with-ajax-request-in-page-with-form-jquery?rq=1)

The problam was as they said there with the `function(event)` so I changed it to `function(e)` wierd why the first one didn't work.

Comment: It is encouraged for you to mark your own answer is as correct for future visitors.

Comment: I will but it says i have to wait untill tommorow

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
          url: "pages/"+page+".php",
          cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $('#main').html(html).css({"max-height":mH-30,"height":mH-30}).jScrollPane();

        $('form').not('#loginf').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var inputs = $(this).serialize();   
            $.ajax({
              url: "pages/"+page+".php?"+inputs+'&action='+param,
              cache: false
            }).done(function( html1 ) {
                update(html1);
                rs();
            }).fail(function (){
                window.location = "/CMS/";
        });
    }); });
```